# Binary and Integer Program in Python

Tags: python, math, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a binary/integer program that I am trying to solve using milp in Python.  Below the image and below is the code I have so far.  When I run it, I get

```
`bounds.lb` and `bounds.ub` must contain reals and be broadcastable to `c.shape`.
```

I believed I accounted for the upper and lower bounds in the "bounds" variable.  But apparently not.  What is missing?

[image]

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint, Bounds 
c = [3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 8, 6, 4, 1]  # x1 to x9 (office setup cost multipliers)
c = c + [0]*36     


A = [
    [1700, 3600, 2100, 2500, 3100, 2700, 4100, 3400, 4100] + [24.3]*9 + [32.4]*9 + [28.9]*9+[26]*9,  # Setup and transfer costs
    [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0] + [0]*36,  # x7 <= x4 + x6
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] + [0]*36,  # x1 + x6 <= 1
    [0]*9 + [1]*9 + [0]*27,  # Chicago
    [0]*18 + [1]*9 + [0]*18,  # Charlotte
    [0]*27 + [1]*9 + [0]*9,  # Pittsburgh
    [0]*36 + [1]*9   # Houston
]

b = [
    14000,  
    0,  
    1,  
    29, 
    22, 
    19,  
    27,  
]

# Define bounds for each variable (0 <= xi <= 1 for binary variables, 0 <= yij)
x_bounds = [(0, 1)] * 9  # Bounds for the x variables
y_bounds = [(0, None)] * 36  # Bounds for the y variables (unbounded upper limit)

# Combine bounds
bounds = x_bounds + y_bounds

integrality = ([1]) * 45

milp(c, integrality = integrality,
    bounds = Bounds(bounds),
     constraints = LinearConstraint(A, b))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, to disable bounds or define "unbounded bounds", one should use `np.inf` or `-np.inf` instead of `None`.

Second, you are currently giving a list of tuples to `scipy.optimize.Bounds` which does not work. Instead you should provide a list of the lower bounds and a list for the upper bounds.

To resolve these issues, you can change the last part of your code to:

```py
# Define bounds for each variable (0 <= xi <= 1 for binary variables, 0 <= yij)
x_bounds = [(0, 1)] * 9  # Bounds for the x variables
y_bounds = [(0, np.inf)] * 36  # Bounds for the y variables (unbounded upper limit)

# Combine bounds
bounds = x_bounds + y_bounds

integrality = ([1]) * 45

l_bounds = [x for (x,y) in bounds]
u_bounds = [y for (x,y) in bounds]

milp(c, integrality = integrality,
    bounds = Bounds(l_bounds, u_bounds),
     constraints = LinearConstraint(A, b))
```

Instead of the list comprehension you could also use the `zip` function for a more concise solution:

```
l_bounds, u_bounds = zip(*bounds)
```

or directly

```
bounds = Bounds(*zip(*bounds))
```

Personally, I prefer the solution using list comprehension as it is clearer to the reader what is happening and with lists of this length, performance is not really an issue.

Comment: Ah!  I see, thank you!  Now I see that my program is not set up correctly, which is a completely different issue.